# Highcharts - applying background image to container div

Tags: highcharts

I need to add a background image to the container div of highcharts

Comment: Hey, "Just do it" © What have you tried?

Comment: background:  url(http://localhost:3000/assets/bg_graph01.png) repeat-x scroll center bottom #FFFFFF;  and background:  url(bg_graph01.png) repeat-x scroll center bottom #FFFFFF;        If I edit the <rect> tag fill attribute from #FFFFFF to url(http://localhost:3000/assets/bg_graph01.png) repeat-x scroll center bottom #FFFFFF it works but need to pass it as rendering the chart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that this will meet your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/RYvcJ/2/.

Simply set transparent color for entire chart and use CSS.

Answer (score 1):

just set this in chart of `highcharts` object ,
and set the x,y position and width and height of image , according to requirement

```
events: {
                load: function() {
                    this.renderer.image('img/SqueezeBallEggOran500.jpg', -28, -5, 345, 301).add();  // add image(url, x, y, w, h)
                }
            }
```